# How to change the text on a button by pulling it from a file

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get my buttons to display the text corresponding to the text in a given file, so far I am successful in hiding the buttons I do not wish to have, but sadly the name's are stuck as "Button2" and so on and so forth. Apparently my post is mainly code so I am required to add more details, I can't think of any of the top of my head, so hopefully this will suffice, but if not please enjoy the following poetry.

Thanks in advance! :{()

```html
Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Public Class Form2
    Dim username As String
    Dim FriendsArray As New List(Of String)
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form1.Hide()
        username = File.ReadAllText("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\TempUser\UserID.txt")
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Program Files\PolarisChatUser\" + username + "\Friends")
            FriendsArray.Add(foundFile)
        Next
        If FriendsArray.Count = 0 Then
            btnF1.Hide()
            btnF2.Hide()
            btnF3.Hide()
            btnF4.Hide()
            btnF5.Hide()
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 1 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            btnF2.Hide()
            btnF3.Hide()
            btnF4.Hide()
            btnF5.Hide()
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 2 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            btnF3.Hide()
            btnF4.Hide()
            btnF5.Hide()
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 3 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            btnF4.Hide()
            btnF5.Hide()
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 4 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            btnF5.Hide()
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 5 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            btnF6.Hide()
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 6 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            btnF7.Hide()
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 7 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            btnF8.Hide()
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 8 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            btnF9.Hide()
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 9 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            btnF10.Hide()
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 10 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            FriendsArray(9) = btnF10.Text
            btnF11.Hide()
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 11 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            FriendsArray(9) = btnF10.Text
            FriendsArray(10) = btnF11.Text
            btnF12.Hide()
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 12 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            FriendsArray(9) = btnF10.Text
            FriendsArray(10) = btnF11.Text
            FriendsArray(11) = btnF12.Text
            btnF13.Hide()
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 13 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            FriendsArray(9) = btnF10.Text
            FriendsArray(10) = btnF11.Text
            FriendsArray(11) = btnF12.Text
            FriendsArray(12) = btnF13.Text
            btnF14.Hide()
        ElseIf FriendsArray.Count = 14 Then
            FriendsArray(0) = btnF1.Text
            FriendsArray(1) = btnF2.Text
            FriendsArray(2) = btnF3.Text
            FriendsArray(3) = btnF4.Text
            FriendsArray(4) = btnF5.Text
            FriendsArray(5) = btnF6.Text
            FriendsArray(6) = btnF7.Text
            FriendsArray(7) = btnF8.Text
            FriendsArray(8) = btnF9.Text
            FriendsArray(9) = btnF10.Text
            FriendsArray(10) = btnF11.Text
            FriendsArray(11) = btnF12.Text
            FriendsArray(12) = btnF13.Text
            FriendsArray(13) = btnF14.Text
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of poetry but the post was now long enough.

Comment: You aren't updating any of your button's Text properties.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry for asking for help again, but I think we did. I think you may have not noticed how terrible my code is. Please scroll down :) But if it turns out to be me who is mistaken please let me know!!

Comment: I did scroll down.  You are updating your List from your buttons, not your buttons from your list.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you very much for your help it is now updating, but we have a slightly  different / more catastrophic issue. Instead of changing it to the text in the file or the name of the file, it has decided to name the file after the directory.

Comment: Use the Path class.  `FriendsArray.Add(Path.GetFileName(foundFile))`

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech it now works perfectly with no issues I will try and not bother you for the rest of this decade. you have really helped me today.

Comment: Do consider changing that code from an IF-Block to a Loop.  Maybe next year...

Comment: Please add Option Strict On

Comment: Please don't call it FriendsArray when it is list. Variable names are important. Wait until you are working with someone elses code.

Comment: "the text in a given file," but you never read the files. Dump the VisualBasic file stuff and get with the mainstream .net classes in System.IO.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in notepad that looks like this.

[image]

Create an array of `Button` with each of your buttons.

With a `For Each` loop set each them to hidden.

Retrieve the text from your `Friends.txt` file. `File.ReadAllLines` returns and array of lines found in the file.

Check that you won't run out of buttons then loop through each line and assign it to the `.Text` property of the button. Be sure to increment the `index` on each iteration.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Buttons() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6}
    For Each bt In Buttons
        bt.Visible = False
    Next
    Dim Friends = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\someUser\Desktop\Friends.txt")
    Dim index As Integer
    If Buttons.Length >= Friends.Length Then
        For Each line In Friends
            Buttons(index).Text = line
            Buttons(index).Visible = True
            index += 1
        Next
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You have more friends than buttons!")
    End If
End Sub
```